# Qt Creator контроль версиий через макросы отключает подсветку кода (цвета)

Tags: c++, linux, c, qtcreator

В Qt Creator-е  "контроль версий" через макросы, отключает подсветку кода (цвета)

```
#define MAJ_VERS_LIB        3   // Major  library software version
#define MIN_VERS_LIB        0   // Minor  library software version
#define RELEASE_LIB         0   // The  library software release
#define CHECK_VERSION_LIB(MAJ, MIN, REL)   ((MAJ == MAJ_VERS_LIB) && (MIN == MIN_VERS_LIB) && (REL >= RELEASE_LIB))

#if CHECK_VERSION_LIB(3, 0, 0)
    // здесь код  
#endif
```

До "включения" контроля версий
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После "включения"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать это мир снова красочным и ярким с макросовым контролем версий ???

---

Проверил в винде, такого "эффекта" там нету :3

Comment: Так а проверка `CHECK_VERSION_LIB` проходит? иначе этот блок будет неактивным

Comment: @VTT странно, код выполняется и компилируется